# How to redirect to error page if iframe is used by other domain to show my Website

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, iframe, meta

Recently my websites content is being stolen by lots of other websites.

What they do is just create an iframe of my website and show specific data on their domain to get high traffic. When I found out, I tried to block it with `htaccess` and `meta` tags.

My webpage that they abuse is an html page which contains an iframe from a subdirectory. 
They don't use that iframe instead they target other contents of html page but my technique to block does not work in Firefox and it blocks my iframe also. It works fine in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.

My `.htaccess` settings - works on Firefox but not on Google chrome and Internet explorer, and also it doesn't show my iframe from same domain:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

My Meta settings - this works on all browser except Firefox:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
```

I have done this temporarily to block my content to use on other websites. 
I want something like a redirect to my custom page, or when user click inside frame it redirects. Any better ideas are welcome.

Comment: Please don't mix up Java with JavaScript.  Different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content negotiation for iframes are handled entirely by the client (browser). The client decides whether to display the content of the iframe or not and whether to honor the **SAMEORIGIN** options (some browser's may not).

As far as htaccess goes, the server doesn't know the difference between a request for a page because someone went to the page directly and a request for a page that was embedded in an iframe, so there's not much you can do within an htaccess file to prevent pages from getting loaded via an iframe.

You can try a number of different things, most of which can be circumvented:

1. Create a separate space for pages that you don't mind being in iframes, everywhere else, use the **SAMEORIGIN** headers
2. For all the pages that you don't want to be embedded in an iframe, check the referer and redirect to a custom page when it is embedded in an iframe:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://your-website.com
   RewriteRule ^ /custom_page.html [L,R=302]
   ```
3. Don't use iframes and set the **SAMEORIGIN** header everywhere.

Comment: @NasirUddin it was an example, you have to tailor the regular expression (which is simply `^` in my example) to stuff that you want to keep from being loaded in someone else's iframe. If you want to exclude images, then change `^` to `!\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|css|js)$` or something

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to *break* out of the frames by redirecting the user to your site via JavaScript:

```
if (top.location != location) {
    top.location.href = document.location.href;
}
```

Comment: which would break out his own iframe too

Comment: that's also a way to protect from XFS